# How to formalize proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm struggling a bit with my discrete maths course and I was wondering if anyone could help me with my assignment. The question I'm working on is,

---

Prove that if a and b are positive integers, then $\frac{a}{b}$ + $\frac{b}{a} \ge 2$

---

This is what I have written down so far, but I'm not sure if it's correct or not...

Proof:

Suppose a, and b are positive integers. Assume that a = 1, and b = 1 as they are the smallest positive integers. Then,

$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} \ge 2 = 2 \ge 2$

Therefore, we know that all positive integers would result in $> 2$

I'm not sure as how to write this out more properly if anyone could give some pointers.

Comment: You're implicitly assuming that if you increase either $a$ or $b$, then $a/b + b/a$ will increase (or at least not decrease). You need to prove that (assuming it's even true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Simplify the inequality you want to show by clearing out the denominators, then realize what you are trying to show is equivalent to $(a-b)^2\ge 0$. Then you can write a very short proof.

By the way, the inequality holds for all positive reals, not just integers. Stating it for integers may throw you off-course since you may be inclined to try induction and thus miss the very simple proof.

Comment: I don't understand where you get $(a-b)^2 \ge 0 from, simplifying would give you \frac{a^2+b^2}{ab} \ge 2 would it not?

Comment: I did say "clear the denominators", right?

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that if $a=b$ then the equality holds. Now suppose that $a>b$, so that $a-b>0$ and $$ (a-b)^{2}>0 \\ a^2-2ab+b^2>0 \\ a^2+b^2>2ab \\ \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{ab}>2 $$ and this last fraction is the same as $ \dfrac{a}{b}+ \dfrac{b}{a}$.